# Data inserted using REST API is lost after rebuilding ASP.NET project

Tags: android, asp.net, sql-server, retrofit2

I'm trying to user retrofit 2 to handle the REST API requests from Android Studio to ASP.NET project and SQL Server. However, every time I rebuild the solution in Visual Studio (where I compile my ASP.NET code), and come back to run the Android app in Android Studio, the data inserted previously from Android is lost.

The problem happens like this: I update the data using PUT method and can see the data has changed, after that I rebuild ASP.NET project, and then use GET to retrieve the data again and the data is reverted back to the starting point. I try using Postman to update and get the data instead of Android but the same problem still happens. I notice that after rebuilding the app, the data in the table is still the same, it is only reverted after I use GET method again. I don't know how to fix it, please help me, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that problem arises because I use the Seed() method in the Configuration.cs file in migrations folder created by entity framework to insert records into the database. If I use the initial-create files instead and leave the seed() method blank then the problem disappears. I never thought that could be the problem because everything is still normal when I insert data through that seed() method with the asp.net web app using MVC controller.